# How to reorder a binary list but keep 1's roughly evenly spread apart from each other in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

I basically want to reorder(don't think this is a shuffling task) a list of 100 binary numbers. The following properties should hold after the reorder: the fixed frequency of 1's should remain, which is 10 and the 1's should be roughly spread apart from each other as shown below, so every 9th, 10th, or 11th digit is a 1. I want this reordering to be random. The trivial approach I had in mind is to track the index of the first 1 in the input list and generate a new start index. Any ideas on other solutions?

```
    x = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: You want to *randomly* reorder the list into a *fixed, deterministic* final state? What? Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Wait, how does this work if every 10th element should be a 1?

Comment: @user2357112 I struggled to explain it, but exactly what you said.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to "reorder" it like this

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Let me edit the question, it can be every 9th, 10th, or 11th but the total frequency should be 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codes as follows:

```
def main():
    from random import shuffle
    from random import randint
    from itertools import chain

    num_of_10th = randint(0, 5) * 2
    num_of_11th = num_of_9th = int((10 - num_of_10th) / 2)

    lsts = []
    for i in range(num_of_10th):
        lsts.append([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

    for i in range(num_of_9th):
        lsts.append([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

    for i in range(num_of_11th):
        lsts.append([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

    shuffle(lsts)

    lsts = list(chain.from_iterable(lsts))
    print(lsts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's list multiplication.

My solution will generate a random `size` between 1 and 10 using `random.randint`. from this `size` I create the `repeated_part` that starts with a 1 and fills in the rest with zero's. For example
when `size` is 5 `repeated_part` will be `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

From the size we can calculate the number of times it fits in a list of 100 `100//spread` and we add one overflow. Now the list will be too large for example with a `size` of 3 the total size of the list is `((100/3)+1)*3 = 102` so we truncate the list to become 100 in length with `[:100]`.

```
import random
size = random.randint(1, 10)

repeated_part = [1] + [0]*(size-1)
result = (repeated_part * (100 // size + 1)) [:100]
```

Note is you want the 1 to not start as first you could use `random.shuffle(repeated_part)` but still hold all your other requirements.